# How can I force Chrome to open new tabs via middle-click/command+click/ctrl+click without focusing on them?

Tags: google-chrome, links, browser-tabs, window-focus

On most webpages in Chrome, I can middle-click/command-click to force a link to open in another tab, and it opens in a new tab while keeping focus on the tab I opened it from.

On some sites/links, however, when I middle-click to open a page in another tab, chrome moves "focus" (not quite the same as HTML/CSS focus, but I'm not sure what the right word is) to that tab, and away from the page I opened it from. This appears to happen with links that would have opened a new tab anyway, and middle-clicking/command-clicking doesn't change the behavior at all from what they would have done anyway.

**Is there some way to force *all* pages opened in a new tab via middle-click/command-click in Chrome to open, while leaving the linking page focused/in the foreground?**

I've tried a few plugins and looked around, but most answers in this area seem oriented towards the opposite solution (forcing new tabs to get focus), or towards arranging where new tabs get created in Chrome's windows/tab ordering, not forbidding focus-stealing.